# Teams application - Bot: How to open up a third party signup page in a new tab/browser when a user types a certain text

Tags: node.js, bots, botframework, microsoft-teams, restify

I am new to teams application development and i am Building a Bot that will communicate with a third party APIs. For users to get information from that third party, they need to sign up to that 3rd party. Can i open a web page in a dialog to sign up user ? How is this possible using Team bot node.js SDK ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to load a page, from a bot, in a Task Module. It basically provides a mini embedded browser experience. See more at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/what-are-task-modules and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/task-modules/task-modules-bots?tabs=nodejs .

Note though that you won't know that the user has actually signed up to the service, only that they opened the "popup". You might be able (depending on the 3rd party's website) to embed their content in an iframe inside your own web page, within the task module, maybe with a button at the bottom to "complete the process" or something like that. That way, your bot will know to proceed. Alternatively, maybe you get a message from the 3rd party when signup is complete.